# Volume of a Solid ($\sqrt{x}+1$), and ($x^2+1$)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to find the volume of the solid that results when the region enclosed by the curves is revolved by the indicted axis.

The problem is:

> $$y=\sqrt{x}+1$$
>   $$y=x^2+1$$
>   $$y=-1$$

I simply have to setup the integral, and the integral which I think can solve the problem is:

$$\pi\int\limits_{0}^1[((\sqrt{x}+1)--1)^2-((x^2+1)--1)^2]dx$$

Comment: Your cross section area is wrong, plus you should be integrating over $y$ since you are revolving around a vertical line.

Comment: @CheeHan I made a mistake its $y=-1$

Comment: That makes more sense then. In that case, your integral is setup correctly (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which given to the specific problem is correct.